postgres 14 enable LDAP authentication
I am trying to enable LDAP authentication for postgres access. Here is my LDAP server which is working fine in other application with node.js
var config = {
                url: 'ldap://111.222.333.44:389/', 
                baseDN: 'DC=ad,DC=justcomp,DC=com',
                username: "justcomp\\" + username,
                password: pswd
            }

I have to use same LDAP for accessing postgres database. Added a new line in pg_hba.conf
host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0       ldap ldapserver=111.222.333.44 ldapport=389 ldaptls=1 ldapprefix=""

is this the right entry i put in pg_hba.conf file or should add "DC=ad,DC=justcomp,DC=com" also ? if yes then please tell the right format.
and trying to connect it from local machine
psql -h 10.11.222.333 -U usersam@justcomp.com -d postgres

where 10.11.222.333 is database server IP. It prompts for the password Password for user usersam@justcomp.com: but when password is entered, it fails with message
psql: error: connection to server at "10.11.222.333", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "usersam@justcomp.com"

I am able to connect to the same database from local pgadmin through database user and password. Also tried with creating user in database create role "usersam@justcomp.com" with login but that also did not work.
please suggest if something is missing here. What am I doing wrong? And is it necessary to create same user in database for every login id in LDAP ?
is this the right way to connect to database
psql -h 10.11.222.333 -U usersam@justcomp.com -d postgres

or it should be something else like
psql -h 10.11.222.333 -U justcomp\usersam -d postgres


You must be hitting a different line in pg_hba.conf otherwise the error message would be
ERROR: LDAP authentication failed for user "..."

Either there is an earlier line in ph_hba.conf that matches, or you didn't reload PostgreSQL to activate the new settings, or there is a syntax error in the configuration file (check the log), or you edited the pg_hba.conf from a different cluster.

There was a line in pg_hba.conf "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 password" which i commented and kept only "host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0       ldap ldapserver=111.222.333.44 ldapport=389 ldaptls=1 ldapprefix=""" Now I am getting psql: error: connection to server at "10.11.222.333", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "usersam@justcomp.com". How to fix this? please help.

A different problem, for which you should ask a new question.

The parameter ldaptls=1 means you will encrypt the traffic at the ldap layer (with StartTLS). It might not be supported or configured by your LDAP server, or Postgres probably doesn't trust your LDAP server's certificate.
Sending passwords in the clear is not great, even internally. Switching to ldaptls=0 will lower the security of this connection to the same level of your Node app, and confirm that this is the actual problem.
If it is, I suggest you proceed to upgrade your LDAP connection security to trusty old TLS for both Node and Postgres.

I solved the problem
To configure the LDAP authentication in postgres , you need to perform below 2 steps.

Add below entry in pg_hba.conf file.
host      all                        all                        0.0.0.0/0                          ldap ldapserver=111.222.333.44 ldapport=389 ldapprefix="justcomp"


Where ldap server and port are mentioned along with the prefix/suffix for loginid (var config in question). Change these entries accordingly.It will set for all remote connections to be allowed through LDAP authentication. Change 0.0.0.0/0 to a suitable value if there is some specific IP to be allowed.

Create same user in database.
create role "user_name" with login;


In database create a user with same as in ldap server. No need to put any password and you may grant permissions on some database to this user, like we do for normal database role/user.
now user "user_name" can be connect to database through pgadmin, psql or any other application. It will accept the user's password as in LDAP.
